# deploy new changes for java based application into commercial server without restarting the server

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

Hi we have developed a java web server using java standard edition. the problem is, every time we made new version of the application, we need to update and restart the server.

what is the best way to overcome the issue? can we try to use **DCEVM** + **hotswapagent**? Are these tools reliable for commercial deployment or only for speeding up the development.

Comment: why need restart the server? undeploy then deploy should be enough. or is it your problem the service is unavailable while deploy? there are a lot of solution to that, but please provide some information about the problem. Hotswap tools are good for development, but it can cause lot of problem in production so it is not recommended.

Comment: @zlaval "undeploy then deploy should be enough. or is it your problem the service is unavailable while deploy" can you please explain what  do you mean udeploy?  the service mainly accept web-socket request from client and pass to business logic layer.  right now, it is running into a production system and always more than 10k customer connected through the system.

Comment: If you have a tomcat server running and your app running inside it, then you can undeploy the old app, and deploy the new one. You do not need to restart the server, just install the new app. But why you deploy(install), the app is unavailable while the process finish (if one node running).  So I curious about which one is the problem, the server restart or the time while the app is unavailable?

Comment: @zlaval it is not a container based application. it has been developed using some asynchronous socket library and business logic has been developed using java. we are deploying the application as a jar and need to replace it for new version and restart the jar. right now it has single instance.  if you suggest about tomcat, then through tomcat is it possible undeploy and deploy again without affecting existing connection and services? sorry to bother you again.

Comment: then a step back, you write tomcat. how do u use it?

Comment: there are not a good solution to replace a running jar in production while your connection not affected. the most common way is to create more instance, gracefully shutdown when need, and install as rolling updates

Comment: @zlaval 
if we deploy multiple instance, still the connection which is connected with that particular instance(websocket connection) will be unavailable for certain period.

Comment: Simple example:
you have 1 running instance with 10k connection. the second instance (new version) starts, accept new connections. the old instance continue to work but not receive new connections. when all connection terminated in the old instance, you can shut down.
I suggest you to update the discription, you provide a lot of valuable informations. And some other: Does it a people-machine communication? How long is the lifetime of a connection etc.
Maybe someone can recommend better solution.